# Comparison doesn't work with the <= operator

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point

I have the following C++ code :

```
float test(0.2);
cout << 1.8 + test << " " << boolalpha << (1.8 + test <= 2) << endl;
```

And this output :

```
2 false
```

But the problem is I should have this output :

```
2 true
```

How can I correct this problem ?

Comment: The error is in floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @chris Ok. And how can I correct the problem ?

Comment: beware `double` promotion (e.g. `1.8F + test != 1.8 + test`) and floating point numerics, this is not decimal arithmetic

Comment: @LucasWillems What about setting a threshold for equality?

Comment: `<=` works. It is `0.2`, `1.8`, the assignment of a `double` constant to a `float` variable, and floating-point `+` that “doesn't work”. In fact `<=` is pretty much the only part of your program that works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Where is the error ?

That's a rounding error. Neither `1.8` nor `0.2` are exactly representable in a binary floating point format, so the actual values used are slightly different. This means that the final result might not be exactly 2; but streaming it to `cout` will round it to a few decimal places and print `2`.

You can see this for yourself by printing it with more precision:

```
cout << setprecision(20) << 1.8 + test << " " << boolalpha << (1.8 + test <= 2) << endl;

// Output: 2.0000000029802320611 false
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/3SkDy6)

> How can I correct this problem ?

That depends on exactly what you're trying to do with floating point numbers. Often, you can simply allow a small tolerance for error, e.g.

```
float tolerance = 1e-6;
cout << 1.8 + test << " " << boolalpha << (1.8 + test <= 2 + tolerance) << endl;
```

but, in general, managing errors and calculating acceptable tolerances can be something of a dark art, requiring a good understanding of the specifics of your algorithm.

Comment: the implicit cast to `double` isn't helping either

Answer (score 0):

One way of working around the problems associated with floating-point arithmetic is to compare for equality using a threshold instead of using the raw values.

That is, instead of doing something like

```
double a = // some value
double b = // another value

if (a == b)
    // ...
```

you do the following

```
if (abs(a - b) <= 1e-5)
    // ...
```

which accounts for some error. The actual threshold value need not be exactly `1e-5`, you could choose another.